# ADO.NET Entities not picking up an FK relationship

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I've got a table "Persons" (**PersonId**, Name, Address) which contains information about people. I then subclass this information with tables "Clients" (**PersonId**, DateJoined) and Victims (**PersonId**, DateAssassinated).

In SSMS I have established an FK relationship `FK_Clients_Persons` and `FK_Victims_Persons` where the Primary Key is Persons.PersonId and the foreign key is the eponymous field in the Clients and Victims tables respectively. In SSMS I cannot see any obvious functional difference between these relationships.

However, in ADO.NET Entities when I create the model from the database, the tool does not identify `FK_Victims_Persons` but it **does** recognise `FK_Clients_Persons`. It just treats Victims.PersonId as a simple field and doesn't generate relationship members for it. The missing FK relationship does not appear in the Constraints tree of the Model Browser, but the other one does.

I have no idea why this is, has anyone faced this problem before?

No matter how many times I start over, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Might be helpful if you posted the related EDMX to see what has happened.

Comment: is personId primary key in both the Clients and Victims table ?

Comment: Yes, PersonId is the primary key in Clients and Victims.

The EDMX file was brand new. When I open it in the XML editor it just has Victims.PersonId as a simple integer field (thought it does recognise it as the PK).

Comment: If you manually add the relationship in the designer and then run a query that uses it, do you get an exception?  Maybe that has some more information in it (or it just works and then maybe it's a weird bug in the designer)